# Sending mass emails via Php (Expert opinion)

Tags: php, email

I have a requirement where I have to send emails to thousands of users. The basic `mail(parameter...)` of php is good but for this scenario, I don't want to iterate over emails and send one by one.

Looked at a number of question but didn't find a relevant answer for shooting mass emails in one go.

queueing is another option but if we see that will do that same job, dequeue an email from the queue and would send the mail to that email.

Is there any way to send mass emails quickly, like 1 shoot may send to an email to 40,000 users in an instance?

Another way to make a huge line of EMAILS (comma separated) and send them using BCC but I guess BCC and CC both have limits (is that so?)

Comment: Yes, there is limits. Here is the doc from Google (if you are going to use Gmail SMTP): https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Comment: @Nikhil but I will not be using google's mail server. I will be using the linux' smail server ..

Comment: Put the address in an array and execute array when the mail(); function is called

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). This is an ideal email solution for mass mailing through PHP.

Answer (score -1):

you can set receivers as many as you want in $to parameter with comma seperate value like this: $to="test1.mail@email.com,test2.mail@email.com"

Comment: is there any limit on the number of emails?

Comment: i think it has no limits to send mail, however you have to test it.